# Есть ли аналог iframe в jsf

Tags: iframe, xhtml, jsf

Вот делаю станицу для сайта и использованием jsf. И хочу, чтобы по клику на пункт меню рядом показывалась другая xhtml - страница, как в iframe на странице html. Но не знаю, как это сделать, т.к. iframe не отображает ничего.

**Как использовать iframe в jsf?**

**Может в jsf для этого есть специальный компонент?**

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться PrimeFaces DialogFramework, реализован он как раз на для открытия произвольных .xhtml страниц во frame. Либо как вариант статически задавать в разметке места, куда будет грузиться содержание другой страницы (ui:insert или ui:include).